# Creating a list of dataframes from a daraframe in python

Tags: python, r, pandas, list

```
df = 
    c1  c2
    ds  43
    ds  34
    ds  32
    foo 34
    foo 32
```

I want to create list of dataframes from  `df`, split based on the column `c1` and assign rownumber.

The output `list` should be something like this from which i can later select individual dataframes

```
out_list:

[[1]]
c1   c2  rownum
ds   43  1
ds   34  2
ds   32  3
[[2]]
c1   c2  rownum
foo  34  1
foo  32  2
```

In `R`, I can do this by `split` function. How can I do this in Python?

Sample R code,

```
df %>% split(.$c1) %>% map(~mutate(., rownum= row_number()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create columns `row nm` by using `cumcount` on groupby. Next, use listcomp on `groupby` object

```
df['row nm'] = df.groupby('c1').cumcount().add(1)

Out[157]:
    c1  c2  row nm
0   ds  43       1
1   ds  34       2
2   ds  32       3
3  foo  34       1
4  foo  32       2

gb_list = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in df.groupby('c1')]

Out[176]:
[   c1  c2  row nm
 0  ds  43       1
 1  ds  34       2
 2  ds  32       3,     c1  c2  row nm
 0  foo  34       1
 1  foo  32       2]

In [177]: gb_list[0]
Out[177]:
   c1  c2  row nm
0  ds  43       1
1  ds  34       2
2  ds  32       3

In [178]: gb_list[1]
Out[178]:
    c1  c2  row nm
0  foo  34       1
1  foo  32       2
```

Comment: Nice, maybe also include `reset_index` in that list comp? Also maybe the `groupby` call can be cached so it doesn't need to be called twice?

Comment: ah, I see your point. Since OP doesn't say specifically about the index of each sub-dataframe, so I doesn't want to reset it. I agree on `df.groupby('c1')` may be assigned to a variable, and use that variable later. However, on performance there is no different because `groupby` is lazy operator.

Comment: Can you please tell what a  `reset_index` does ?

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran: `reset_index` will reset each sub-dataframe index to rangeindex starting from `0`. Look at current `gb_list[1]` first column is `3, 4`. If you chain `reset_index`, it will be `0, 1`

Comment: where exactly should i add that? while creating gb_list?

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran: I added `reset_index`. Check my updated

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran: you welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

using dictionaries,this gives you flexibility to make dataframe in whatever way you want

```
d = {key: df.loc[value] for key, value in df.groupby("c1").groups.items()}
d.values() #gives you the required output you want
```

further you can format your dataframe in a way you want

```
for k,v in d.items():
    globals()['df_' + str(k)] = pd.DataFrame(v)   #here globals() is used to create and access df name dynamically
    globals()['df_' + str(k)]['rank'] = globals()['df_' + str(k)].groupby('c1').cumcount().add(1)
    globals()['df_' + str(k)].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

your dataframes are `df_ds` and `df_foo`